# Order of calling methods - why does it matter in this example?

Tags: c#, xna

I have the following method, called in my update loop, to check if one of two buttons has been pressed.

```
    private void CheckInputs()
    {
        if (CheckButton(startNewGameButtonTexture, startNewGameButtonPosition))
        {
           //break 1 is here
        }

        if (CheckButton(continueCareerButtonTexture, continueCareerButtonPosition))
        {
           //break 2 is here
        }
    }
```

Buttons are just rectangles, and if the mouse is over them, and the click is released the CheckButton bool returns true:

```
    public bool CheckButton(Texture2D texture, Vector2 vector)
    {
        MouseState CurrentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        bool outcome;

        if (CurrentMouseState.X > vector.X && CurrentMouseState.X < vector.X + texture.Width &&
            CurrentMouseState.Y > vector.Y && CurrentMouseState.Y < vector.Y + texture.Height)
        {
            if (CurrentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && PreviousMouseState == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                outcome = true;
            }
            else
            {
                outcome = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            outcome = false;
        }

        PreviousMouseState = CurrentMouseState.LeftButton;
        return outcome;
    }
```

In the current order, the startNewGameButton works (ie debugging stops at break 1), but the continueCareerButton doesn't work (clicking on the button does not trigger break 2).

But if I change the order of the the checks to this:

```
    private void CheckInputs()
    {
        if (CheckButton(continueCareerButtonTexture, continueCareerButtonPosition))
        {
           //break 2 is here
        }

        if (CheckButton(startNewGameButtonTexture, startNewGameButtonPosition))
        {
           //break 1 is here
        }
    }
```

the continueCareerButton now works (break 2), but the startNewGameButton now doesn't (break 1).

I think the mouse states must not be working properly, but I can't work out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your PreviousMouseState every time you check.

You should be setting it once per frame, the simplest way to do this is inside the `Update()` function:

```
void Update(..) {
    CurrentMouseState := Mouse.GetState()

    // code...

    PreviousMouseState = CurrentMouseState
}
```

Otherwise it will only ever work for the first call of your `CheckButton()` function instead of every call.

Comment: No problemo :) I have done it myself in the past.. :\

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the button is released, you are setting `PreviousMouseState` to `ButtonState.Released` in the first call to `CheckButton`. Thus the second call to `CheckButton` can never return true (because `PreviousMouseState` is almost always equal to `CurrentMouseState.LeftButton`). Don't set `PreviousMouseState` until after both if statements.

Comment: Thanks - answer to scott only because he answered first